# Ecto query Postgres JSON Array for a value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have the following schema, which is a JSONB field for a post table, which will save all tags used.

```
schema "posts" do
  ...
  field :tags, {:array, :string}
  ...
end
```

And it has an array of "tags" as "strings". I'd like to search for a string value inside of this array. I tried:

```
def search_by_tag(query, tag) do
  from p in query,
    where: fragment("? @> ?", p.tags, ^tag)
end
```

But without success, what I'm looking for is a way to search through the JSONB array and found a value if the values exists. Also it should keep the function for the query compatible with non JSONB queries to continue doing like:

```
Blog.Post |> Blog.Post.search_by_tag("tag1") |> Blog.User.active()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@>` function expects the second operant to be array, so:

```
def search_by_tag(query, tag) do
  tags = [tag]
  from p in query,
    where: fragment("? @> ?", p.tags, ^tags)
end
```

Also ecto syntax support such cases by it self:

```
def search_by_tag(query, tag) do
  from p in query,
    where: tag in p.tags
end
```

Also for composable queries `Blog.Post.search_by_tag("tag1") |> Blog.User.active()`, you might consider to use ["pipe-based syntax"](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-macro-api)